# How to display different content html pages in master page's content section based on menu selections

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

How can I show different content pages in master page's content layout section based on menu selection from header.

Let's say if I select About-> Mission I want to show HtmlPage1.html let's say if I select About->Vision I want to show HtmlPage2.html

**MyHeader Menu in BasePage.html**

```
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a href="./" class="navbar-brand">Bootstrap Menu</a>
                </div>
                <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="HtmlPage1.html">Mission</a></li>
                                <li><a href="HtmlPage2.html">Vision</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Products</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Services</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>

  </div>
 <div style="margin-top:100px; text-align:center;"> 
            **********************Main Content Here****************************

  </div>
  <div>
```

Comment: Consider using [`ngRoute`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) and display content with `<div ng-view></div>` through templates/partials

Comment: @AlekseySolovey can you just post some sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `ngRoute` (from `angular-route` module) for displaying content with templates/partials. You would need to add `<div ng-view></div>` instead of `*Main Content Here*` to load your templates. These partials don't need any headers like `<!DOCTYPE html>` since they are inserted into your HTML and rendered.

Here is a small demo:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
      templateUrl: "main.html"
    })
    .when("/page1", {
      templateUrl: "HtmlPage1.html"
    })
    .when("/page2", {
      templateUrl: "HtmlPage2.html"
    })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">

  <p><a href="#!/">Main</a></p>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#!/page1">Mission</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!/page2">Vision</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div style="text-align:center;">
    <div ng-view></div>
  </div>


  <!-- These can be separate files in your directory -->
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="main.html">
    Main page
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="HtmlPage1.html">
    Mission page
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="HtmlPage2.html">
    Vision page
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Alternatively you can use `ng-include` (for headers, footers) or directives (for small features like login section).

Comment: Thanks @Aleksey Solovey

Comment: When I am running this I am getting page is unresponsive error wait or cancel alert is showed

Comment: Also when I am clicking Mission or Vision its not navigating to specific page

Comment: @user1030181 by "separate files" I meant without `<script>` tag, just the content. (Those scripts are for `ng-templates`, which simulate separate files)